# How was the transformer reduced in this Thevenin equivalent circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Below is an example of a one-port network and how to find its output impedance by using Thevenin model:

[image]

I can understand that Vi is set to zero since it is an independent source. But how was the coupled coils or transformer with 1:a ratio is reduced to the third circuit diagram? I mean how was a^2*R1 and a^2*L1 was obtained? Only the ratio 1:a is given not the inductance.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer is presumed to be ideal with a magnetization inductance of L1 hence, when Vi is set to zero, the impedance on that side of the ideal transformer is R1||sL1.

That impedance is transformed by the turns ratio squared (\$a^2\$) to the secondary output side hence it becomes: -

$$a^2(R_1 || sL_1)$$

Given that it is in series with R2 it should now be clear.

Comment: I dont understand. The transformer has primary and secondary coils call it as L2 and L3 and turns ratio 1:a. We dont know what L2 and L3. We only know L1. I have no idea how this leads that way.

Comment: Can you maybe try to use L2 and L3 in your explanation, like we have three inductors in the circuit where two are magnetically coupled?

Comment: @panicattack - look below that transformer - it says "ideal". An ideal transformer has infinite coil inductance. There is no need to use L2 and L3. Just think about it a while.

Comment: So two coils L2 and L3 have infinite inductance? So then how are they reduced this way mathematically? I dont know how the transition is made step by step here. Is L1 coupled to the transformer?

Comment: They are infinite inductance and don't need to be reduced or manipulated in any way. An infinite inductance in parallel with L1 makes a combined inductance of.... L1.

Comment: Is there any math or theorem to demonstrate what you say? What you say is result, Im wondering the derivation and the theory behind this conclusion.

Comment: [An ideal transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#Ideal_transformer). No there is no math just a definition but from that definition you can conclude what I have stated in my answer.

Comment: @panicattack have you grasped this yet?

Comment: No but Im going to ask a new question. I probably came to a point but after a point Im stuck. I will open a new question with some simulations. Im preparing it and soon gonna open and also let you know from here as well. It is really not easy to articulate a question "being clear" in written language especially if it is engineering topic. So Im trying to express what I know and where Im stuck at.